# Toggle Image On-click Using JavaScript/Jquery in list of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I am new to web language and need help with toggling image.

So I have a list of divs displaying images, and the source of the image is from a database.

I want the image to toggle in a way to replace the url from the database with another url from the same database table (e.g. switch before_url to after_url).

I have tried a few ways and the closest I got is click on one image, but it updates for all elements.

The code below is something I've tried (yes I'm trying to toggle by clicking button)

--

**Update:** 
I have found a solution to my problem. I assigned individual unique IDs to the elements, so when passing the element on-click, it can do change to only one element at a time.

Thank you to those tried answering my questions, I really appreciate it! 
:)

**some CSS:**

```
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 16px;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
{% for c in card_list %}
    <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="myCard_before" src="{{ c.img_url_before }}" style="width:100%;" />
          <img class="myCard_after" src="{{ c.img_url_after }}" style="width:100%;display:none" />
          <div class="container">
          <h4>{{ c.card_title }}</h4>
          <input class="button" type="button" onclick="changeImg1() "value="before" />
          <input class="button" type="button" value="after" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
  console.log(elements);

  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function(event) {
      this.classList.toggle('red');
      this.classList.toggle('myCard_afterEvol');
    }
  }

  function changeImg1() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].onclick = function(event) {
        if(document.getElementById("myCard_before").style.display == "none") {
          document.getElementById("myCard_before").style.display = "";
          document.getElementById("myCard_after").style.display ="none";
        }
      }
    }
  }


</script>
```

I have found something really similar to what I want the code to behave like, but instead of a CSS change, I want it to toggle between the images.

https://codepen.io/michaelhhdk/pen/pPyqmL?editors=0010

Any help/suggestion on what I should look at would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the js script used as follows

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
  //For each element in the container array, add an onclick event.
  container[i].onclick = function(event) {
 var newUrl = "https://google.com"; // Create new url
 $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
    this.classList.toggle('red');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.box {
  background: #ddd;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 60px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.red {
  background: IndianRed;
  padding: 80px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use $(this) in onClick event to change particular element. Check Following

```
   <input class="button" type="button" onclick="changeImg1(this) "value="before" />


function changeImg1(ele) {
    if($(ele).style.display == "none") {
       $(ele).style.display = "";
       $(ele).style.display ="none";
    }
```